# ERP, CRM (with sales support), and integrated DMS

Tags: windows, document-management, crm, erp

I am searching for Windows software with the following capabilities:

- **CRM** (addresses, contacts, sales support, etc.)
- **ERP** (sales, purchasing, article management, support for many warehouses, support for online shop / offline store, custom reports (invoices/reminder/etc.))
- Integrated **DMS**
- And all this in **German language** (German jurisdiction)
- Not more expensive than **500 EUR** (a demo version for testing would be great)

Is there such a thing?

**Update**: 
I found meanwhile 2 software. I give you later pros and contras.

- [Addware Warenwirtschaft](http://www.addware.de/warenwirtschaft/uebersicht/)
- [Lexware Warenwirtschaft Pro](http://shop.lexware.de/warenwirtschaft/lexware-warenwirtschaft-pro)

Comment: Compiere seams to complicated and to powerfull, but I test it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Compiere](http://www.compiere.com/products/compare-editions/) with [Adempiere](http://www.adempiere.org/) (DMS).

They won't cost you anything for the community version, but I must tell you setting this up is not an easy task, you will have to read a lot the documentation and be prepared for some time testing and fully understanding all the process flows.

It has several language packs including German.